# interactive java invocation is fine but the same in a script fails

Tags: java, bash

My script is not running but the same command interactively seems to work. First I try a * wildcard and it fails with a "could not find or load" probably because I want the wildcard to get a Java interpretation, not the Linux interpretation. So I quote the wildcard and then it works: (Java gets the wildcard and interprets it I believe to mean "all the JAR files"). Next I try the same from a script and it fails.

```
root@server0:~/serverDeployment/application# java -enableassertions 
-classpath export/ohana1/* info.zqxj.trader1.CommandProcessor help
Error: Could not find or load main class export.ohana1.commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
root@server0:~/serverDeployment/application# java -enableassertions 
-classpath export/ohana1/"*" info.zqxj.trader1.CommandProcessor help
AssertionsEnabled
echoing arguments at the runtime local date 2016 09 06 local time 17:15:01.4...
help 
END of echoed arguments.
CommandProcessor: Will process the >help< argument.
CommandProcessor: END of processing the >help< argument.
root@server0:~/serverDeployment/application# cat runner.sh
#!/bin/bash
CLASSPATH='-classpath export/ohana1/"*"'
echo "$CLASSPATH"
java -enableassertions "$CLASSPATH" info.zqxj.trader1.CommandProcessor help
exit 0

root@server0:~/serverDeployment/application# ./runner.sh
-classpath export/ohana1/"*"
Unrecognized option: -classpath export/ohana1/"*"
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

The option is `-classpath` but for some reason the entire `-classpath export/ohana1/"*"` is taken to be an option. Why is this happening?

**Edit: Costi Ciudatu points out that I double quoted the string `-classpath` which is true it got double quoted on the line with the java invocation so I stopped doing that in this example that follows. However, it still fails.**

```
root@server0:~/serverDeployment/application# cat runner.sh
#!/bin/bash
CLASSPATH='-classpath export/ohana1/"*"'
echo $CLASSPATH
java -enableassertions $CLASSPATH info.zqxj.trader1.CommandProcessor help
root@server0:~/serverDeployment/application# ./runner.sh
-classpath export/ohana1/"*"
Error: Could not find or load main class info.zqxj.trader1.CommandProcessor
```

BTW: The echo command seems to indicate that the double quote does no harm, both times I get the contents of the single quote. So `echo "$VAR"` seems to do the same as `echo $VAR` so perhaps there is no harm doing the same in the java invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you put both the option and the value it in double quotes. Try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
CLASSPATH='export/ohana1/*'
java -enableassertions -cp "$CLASSPATH" info.zqxj.trader1.CommandProcessor help
```

Comment: Your's works but I don't understand the harm of treating "-classpath" as a string.

Comment: This also fails but it's not clear to me why...CLASSPATH='-classpath export/ohana1/"*"'
java -enableassertions $CLASSPATH info.zqxj.trader1.CommandProcessor help

Comment: In this second example, I believe the -classpath string is not in double quotes.

Comment: Yeah, the whole idea is to not have `"-classpath $CLASSPATH"` in double quotes, as that is interpreted by the shell as a single word/token. This is what causes that error.

Comment: But it's not in double quotes in the second example, only single quotes. And I've never seen this single token behaviour described so it's surprising.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't noticed your edit. If you put those double quotes around `*` inside the single-quoted string, your result will be an invalid path: literally `export/ohana1/"*"`.

Comment: Yes but `export/ohana1/"*"` seems to be necessary interactively. See the top of my question.

Comment: That's required in the interactive shell (as it otherwise eagerly expands the glob to actual files). But for the java command, it ends up as `export/ohana1/*` (which is what you want). When you put that in single quotes, however, it will preserve the quotes in the value: `echo export/ohana1/"*" 'export/ohana1/"*"'` spot the difference :)

Comment: If globbing can happen in a script then it seems that what is needed interactively should be the same as what is needed in a script. Still confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122785/discussion-between-costi-ciudatu-and-h2onacl).